# Spring Boot 3.1 with compose and postgres dependencies fails running contextLoad test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, testcontainers

I just created a `Spring Boot 3.1.3` project with dependencies as below:

- Web
- Data JPA
- Test
- Docker compose
- Postgres
- Testcontainers

It includes a `compose.yml` file with initial settings for `postgres` image. I run the application and all fine!

Then I run `mvn clean test` command and I get this error while running `contextLoad()` test:

```
[ERROR] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests.contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0.028 s  <<< ERROR!
```

and this is stack-trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
        ... 113 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:186)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.PropertiesJdbcConnectionDetails.getDriverClassName(PropertiesJdbcConnectionDetails.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:55)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:117)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
        ... 114 more
```

Should i exclude auto-configuring the data source in the tests? Or there are new ways of handling database connection configurations?

Comment: The error message says it couldn’t find a suitable driver class. Do you’ve a dependency on the database driver?

Comment: I know how to fix this in boot versions before 3.1. There are a lot additions in this new version for docker and testcontainers and I guess there is way to do it in a new way.

Comment: The fix has always been the same,, and It’s got nothing to do with Spring at all. add a dependency to the driver in your build file.

Comment: Can you maybe submit at least pom.xml and application.yaml files?

Answer (score 0):

I reported an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/37276) for this and Spring boot team closed that issue with this comment:

> This is to be expected as the Docker Compose support is disabled by default when running tests and the test that is generated by https://start.spring.io isn't yet [configured to use Testcontainers](https://github.com/spring-io/start.spring.io/issues/1247).

As a workaround, I just added an `H2` dependency as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This way, `Spring Boot` will not throw any exception.